# How can I use baked lighting on sprites? / How to light up a large area in 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I'm having trouble figuring out how to light up large area(s) of sprites in Unity 2D. My previous knowledge on Unity's lighting is zero.

I first tried using a large amount of point lights and using the "Sprites/Diffuse" material, but about only five would actually render at a time, so I guess there's a limit on that.

Then I tried putting in an area light. That didn't do anything, so that's when I started doing research about baked lighting on sprites (and baked lighting in general). I found stuff like [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/bake-sprites-lightmaps.446721/) but I couldn't get it to work either because it's outdated or because I don't know what I'm doing. Other answers I've come across seem to assume that the reader knows anything about lighting in Unity in the first place which, to be honest, I don't. Unity's documentation website had some information on it, but no tutorials that go into how to set up baked lighting.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of materials (like using the "Standard" shader for the sprites instead of "Sprites/Diffuse", emission, ect.) and I enabled "Baked Global Illumination" in Lighting>Settings.

If baked lighting isn't possible on sprites (or isn't worth the trouble), what are the alternatives?

Edit: I made sure not to have the lights pointing the wrong direction, and I do realise that Unity2D is just like painting onto a piece of paper in Unity3D. I was able to get point lights to work, but only a few at a time. I don't need to do the entire screen at once, I need to do a large *specific* area at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I never even thought about going into the asset store. I found this for free, and it looks like it will work: [Light2D](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/light2d-gpu-lighting-system-30953).

Answer (score 0):

some tips...

working with sprites your in 2d... when you add a light, switch to 3d mode, and rotate to make sure your light is pointed at your objects, and oriented so as not to be on the same plane, or level with them, as this will cast all the light behind them.

if your trying to light up everything on the screen(in camera) attach an area light to the camera at the cameras position, point it where the camera points, and then in the inspector on the right, you can change its variables. intensity, range, width, height etc.

Emissive Texture:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oa6kW5HhRd4

Comment: Yes, I made sure not to have the lights pointing the wrong direction, and I do realise that Unity2D is just like painting onto a piece of paper in Unity3D. Maybe I wasn't clear, but I was able to get point lights to work, but only a few at a time. I don't need to do the entire screen at once. I need to do a large _specific_ area at once.

Comment: ok so go back and re add your sprites/diffuse material to your sprites, add a directional light where you want your light, make sure its positioned and oriented, then adjust its intensity and range. i see what your saying i just had to do a little playing around, but i figured it out. without that diffuse material though they wont take any light so thats absolutely needed.

Comment: Thank you, but I was already able to figure out that part, but the problem is when I want to light up an area that isn't a circle. My situation in this case is that I essentially need to have the floor emit light. Right now my temporary solution is to manually place a few large point lights, but it looks odd. Is there any way to light up a rectangular area?

Comment: check out the link i just added to my answer. it will show you how to make the floor emit its own light.   i actually just learned that myself, now im going to go play with it

Comment: I've tried emissive, but I can't get it (nor baked lighting) to work on sprites, which is the problem.